# Can't connect to Github from one PC, every other website works fine

Tags: networking, github, connectivity

Running Ubuntu 16.04, I can connect to other websites fine:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.25.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nrt12s13-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.25.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=42.6 ms

ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.137.246.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from media-router-fp1.prod1.media.vip.gq1.yahoo.com (98.137.246.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=252 ms
```

But I can't ping Github or access it in my browser:

```
ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.255.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.60 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

However, from another PC on the same network everything works fine:

```
ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.255.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-255-112-sea.github.com (192.30.255.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=141 ms
```

What's going on here? I have a feeling it's something to do with Github's IP address's first octet being the same as the local one: `192.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

EDIT: Output of `sudo route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.179.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.179.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

Comment: Do you have any dns cache service installed?

Comment: AFAIK I haven't installed one.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo route -n` and add it to your question?

Comment: Check the netmask of your network interface, maybe it's 255.0.0.0

Comment: @jcbermu The netmask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @Zwans I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: What is the interface `enp0s31f6`?

Comment: Ah, I see now, Zwans. Another interface has a mask of 255.0.0.0 and is on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx. I'll add an answer if changes that mask fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there was another interface on a local network (with the address 192.168.xxx.xxx) that had the bitmask set to `255.0.0.0`. I used `nmtui` to change the bitmask of that interface to `255.255.0.0` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: never route non private IP except if you perfectly know what your doing. This would lead to all sorts of issue. Always use the smallest network to route, a too general route is usually a bad sign.